# How to change the size of a column in a view dynamically

Tags: sql, sql-server

The problem is that i have a table Employee in which a field employeeAddress(varchar(200)), I m creating a View EmployeeView in SQL Server and i want to change it to the employeeAddress(varchar(50)), means i want to show only 50 characters of employeeAddress column and after that concatenate with '...'.

For Example :- New Delhi(Suppose it is of 100 character)
i want to change it in to the EmployeeView as

NewDel(suppose it is the 50 characters) then it should be as "NewDel..."

Comment: That's a strange requirement. Why you want to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most of the existing answers seem to be missing the need for the conditional ellipsis:

```
CREATE VIEW dbo.EmployeeView
WITH SCHEMABINDING
AS
    SELECT
        /* Other Columns */
        CASE
          WHEN LEN(EmployeeAddress) > 50
            THEN SUBSTRING(EmployeeAddress,1,50) + '...'
          ELSE EmployeeAddress
        END as EmployeeAddress
    FROM
        dbo.Employee
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this

```
create view DemoView as select name=SUBSTRING(name,1,50)+'...' from tableName;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE VIEW vw_tbl
AS
    SELECT col = LEFT(col, 50) 
    FROM tbl
```